# Issues showing Deserialized Json in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model, model-view

This is my first time posting here and I have tried searching, but I can't get any of the suggested resolutions to work for me.

I am trying to take the Json response from an api call and display it in a web grid view.  Currently my grid only displays the first part of the json.  See picture.  I am not sure if its because my view isn't correct or if it is because of my deserialization.

[New Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZcWN.jpg)

I want it to display each rate from the carrier in the response json below:

[
   `{`
"success": true,
"rate_response": [
{
"scac": "DAFG",
"service": "dayton_ltl",
"service_human": "Dayton Freight",
"carrier": "dayton",
"carrier_human": "Dayton",
"estimated_transit_days": 1,
"cost": "$145.53"
},
{
"service": "FEDEX_EXPRESS_SAVER",
"service_human": "FedEx Express Saver",
"carrier": "fedex",
"carrier_human": "Fedex Parcel",
"estimated_transit_days": 3,
"cost": "$179.78"
},
],
"rate_response_errors": [
{
"carrier": "BCP Transportation",
"message": "No Mileage Detected"
}
],
"pick_ticket_number": "99999",
"bol_number": "4861521889418148"
}
]`

Current Controller

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(jsonString);
return View("GridView", result);
```

ShipResponse class:

```
public class RateResponse
{

    [JsonProperty("scac")]
    public string scac { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("service")]
    public string service { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("service_human")]
    public string service_human { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("carrier")]
    public string carrier { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("carrier_human")]
    public string carrier_human { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("estimated_transit_days")]
    public int estimated_transit_days { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("cost")]
    public string cost { get; set; }
}

public class RateResponseError
{

    [JsonProperty("carrier")]
    public string carrier { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string message { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{

    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public bool success { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("rate_response")]
    public IList<RateResponse> rate_response { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("rate_response_errors")]
    public IList<RateResponseError> rate_response_errors { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pick_ticket_number")]
    public string pick_ticket_number { get; set; }
}


}
```

GridView.cshtml:

```
@model List<P21.Rules.Visual.Areas.SwanleapQuote.Models.RootObject>
     @{
       ViewBag.Title = "GridView";
       Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_VisualRuleLayout.cshtml";
}
<div>

   <hr />
</div>

 @foreach (var item in Model)
{ 
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <form>
        <h3>Rates</h3>
        @{
            var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, canSort: true, rowsPerPage: 2);
            grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);

         }

        <div>
            @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new
 {
   id = "grid",
   @class = "table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed"
 },
        emptyRowCellValue: "No Records Found",
        headerStyle: "grid-header")
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-warning pull-right" type="submit">Return   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i></button>
    </form>

    </div>
```

My current result only shows:

> Success  ,      rate_response  ,     rate_response_errors   ,   pick_ticket_number

I would like it to show me:

> service_human,   estimated_transit_days,  Cost

Comment: I see no code, no picture, and no JSON. Please post code and data as text, [not as pictures](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: Sorry this is my first time posting.  Thank you for the quick response.  I added some code and pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code :

```
public class RateResponse
{
    public string scac { get; set; }
    public string service { get; set; }
    public string service_human { get; set; }
    public string carrier { get; set; }
    public string carrier_human { get; set; }
    public int estimated_transit_days { get; set; }
    public string cost { get; set; }
}

public class RateResponseError
{
    public string carrier { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public List<RateResponse> rate_response { get; set; }
    public List<RateResponseError> rate_response_errors { get; set; }
    public string pick_ticket_number { get; set; }
    public string bol_number { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize Object :

```
var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
```

JsonString :

```
[{
"success": true,
"rate_response": [
{
"scac": "DAFG",
"service": "dayton_ltl",
"service_human": "Dayton Freight",
"carrier": "dayton",
"carrier_human": "Dayton",
"estimated_transit_days": 1,
"cost": "$145.53"
},
{
"service": "FEDEX_EXPRESS_SAVER",
"service_human": "FedEx Express Saver",
"carrier": "fedex",
"carrier_human": "Fedex Parcel",
"estimated_transit_days": 3,
"cost": "$179.78"
}],
"rate_response_errors": [
{
"carrier": "BCP Transportation",
"message": "No Mileage Detected"
}
],
"pick_ticket_number": "99999",
"bol_number": "4861521889418148"
}
]
```

.CSHTML page

```
You can use foreach loop for create table as per your requirement
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested (see in original post).  Now I am getting the data back from the first level of the Json.  I am getting the values from pick_ticket_number and success in a grid.  How can I get to the next level.  When I tried changing the model to RateResponse instead of RootObject I get the column headings I am looking for (Scac, Service, Service_Human, Estimated_Ship_days, etc)  but they are all blank.

Comment: You can get expected values with :

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
 var x = item.rate_response;
 foreach(var item2 in x)
 {
   string scac = item2.scac;
  string service_human = item2.service_human;
 }
}

Comment: Thank you for your help, Tushar.  That worked.  I forgot about this question until I posted a new question.